# Javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this XML:

```
<[Results]>
    <[Data]>
        <[div]>THIS IS HTML! <[/div]>
    <[/Data]>
<[/Results]>
```

What is the regular expression to get `<[div]>THIS IS HTML!<[/div]>`?

Comment: You'll find this question of great use for your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You should not use regular expressions to parse XML. Usually you'll have an XML parser and perhaps XPath available to get the element. The XPath to get the `div` would then be `/Results/Data/div` – if one assumes the brackets are not present. You should add more context to your question such as where the script runs and if a standard library is available to you.

Comment: I second @Gabi. Don't parse XML/HTML with regular expressions. They aren't regular languages.

Comment: @duckmike I've updated my answer, please read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<\[div\]>.+?<\[\/div\]>
```

Will match anything inside the div tags.

Though I am complied to tell you that that regex is **NOT** perfect. If you want to parse XML, you should use an XML parser.

Do read [***this post***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on the subject thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Do not parse XML with regexes. Do not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert this to actual XML, instead of a string, you could use the getElementsByTagName method to find all div tags and the innerHTML(?) property (or innerText/textContent depending on what you want)

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid catch <´s in the body if you have 2 or more DIVs. Try this:

<[div]>[^<]<[/div]>

Comment: And what is supposed to happen when the string looks like `<[div]><p>Content here...</p><[/div]>`. I guess it should match that too...

Comment: It´s true. Inner expressions must accept all tags but <[/div]>

Comment: But `<[div]><[div]>Content here...<[/div]><[/div]>` is also valid... Really, if you want to parse XML, use an XML parser.